# How can i pragmatically fill a field collection when creating a new node?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm creating nodes pragmatically but I don't know how to fill field_collection fields. Most of the examples i've seen have field_collections being updated from existing nodes and i'm not entirely certain they can also be used when creating new nodes.

```
function createNode($Obj){
  global $user;
  $node = entity_create('node', array(
    'type' => 'event',
    'uid' => 1,
    'status' => 1,
    'comment' => 0,
    'promote' => 0,
  ));
  $body = "<p>" . (string)$Obj->BuildingCode;
  $body .= " " . (string)$Obj->RoomNumber . "</p>";
  $body .= "<p>" . (string)$Obj->Description . "</p>";

  $entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  $entity->language(LANGUAGE_NONE);
  $entity->title = (string)$Obj->ActivityName;
  $entity->body->set(array(
    'value' => $body,
    'summary' => (string)$Obj->Description,
    'format' => 'full_html',
  ));
  $entity->field_activityid = (string)$Obj->ActivityId;
  $entity->field_location_room = (string)$Obj->RoomNumber;
  $entity->field_location_building = (string)$Obj->BuildingCode;
  $entity->field_location_address->set(array(
    'country' => '',
    'thoroughfare' => '',
    'premise' => '',
    'locality' => '',
    'administrative_area' => '',
    'postal_code' => '',
  ));
  // $enitity->field_event_organizer->set(array(
  //   'field_event_presenter_name' => (string)$Obj->ContactFirstName,
  //   'field_event_presenter_title' => "TEST",
  //   'field_event_presenter_organizati' => "ORG",
  // ));

  $values = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_event_organizer',
    'field_event_presenter_name' => array(
      LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => (string)$Obj->ContactFirstName)),
    ),
    'field_event_presenter_title' => array(
      LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => "PTITLE")),
    ),
    'field_event_presenter_organizati' => array(
      LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => "PORGANI")),
    ),
  );

  $entity->save();
}
```

EDIT:
main collection field:
[image: picture of main field_collection]
sub fields:
[image: picture of field_collection fields to be created]

I tried to add a modified version the code below in hopes it would work for me:

```
$field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array(
    'field_name' => 'field_event_organizer'
  ));
  $field_collection_item->setHostEntity('node', $node);
  $field_collection_item->field_event_organizer_name = "PROG NAME";
  $field_collection_item->save();

  $entity->field_event_organizer = $field_collection_item->item_id;
```

However i got an error
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property propertyInfo. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line 354 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

EDIT:
Re-tweaked the answer given to me by SN_26 and it manages to create the node with the field_collection filled in but I get the following error message:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Status message Registration settings have been saved.
Error messageEntityMetadataWrapperException: There can be only numerical keyed items in a list. in EntityListWrapper->get() (line 1038 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).
```

full updated code:

```
function createNode($Obj){
  global $user;
  var_dump($Obj);
  $node = entity_create('node', array(
    'type' => 'event',
    'uid' => 1,
    'status' => 1,
    'comment' => 0,
    'promote' => 0,
  ));
  $body = "<p>" . (string)$Obj->BuildingCode;
  $body .= " " . (string)$Obj->RoomNumber . "</p>";
  $body .= "<p>" . (string)$Obj->Description . "</p>";

  $entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  $entity->language(LANGUAGE_NONE);
  $entity->title = (string)$Obj->ActivityName;
  $entity->body->set(array(
    'value' => $body,
    'summary' => (string)$Obj->Description,
    'format' => 'full_html',
  ));
  $entity->field_activityid = (string)$Obj->ActivityId;
  $entity->field_location_room = (string)$Obj->RoomNumber;
  $entity->field_location_building = (string)$Obj->BuildingCode;
  $entity->field_location_address->set(array(
    'country' => '',
    'thoroughfare' => '',
    'premise' => '',
    'locality' => '',
    'administrative_area' => '',
    'postal_code' => '',
  ));
  $entity->field_event_date[0]->set(array(
    'value' => _unix_date_time($Obj->StartDate, $Obj->StartMinute),//Y-m-d H:i:s
    'value2' => _unix_date_time($Obj->EndDate, $Obj->EndMinute),
  ));

  $field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array(
    'field_name' => 'field_event_organizer'
  ));
  $field_collection_item->setHostEntity('node', $node);
  $field_collection_item->field_event_organizer_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = "PROG NAME";
  $field_collection_item->save();

  $entity->field_event_organizer[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $field_collection_item->item_id;

  $entity->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error I found that this works by **NOT** assigning the `$field_collection_item` to the entity was the correct way to do this.

```
$field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_event_organizer'));
$field_collection_item->setHostEntity('node', $node);
$field_collection_item->field_event_organizer_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = array('value' => $fullName);
$field_collection_item->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick to insert a new field collection item:

```
$field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_some_collection'));
$field_collection_item->setHostEntity('node', $entity);
$field_collection_item->field_my_field_in_the_fc[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'hello';
$field_collection_item->save();

$entity->field_some_collection[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['value'] = $field_collection_item->item_id;
```

Comment: I'm not exactly loading a node. I'm creating a node and filling the fields for a node type that was made using the Drupal UI.

Comment: See above for the edited version.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This didn't work. The last thing i posted semi worked, it can create a node with the field collection but it also crashes. The code you gave me gives me the following error: `EntityMetadataWrapperException: There can be only numerical keyed items in a list. in EntityListWrapper->get() `